# Rails flash is not working on proxy pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, shopify, flash-message

I'm developing a Shopify app using ruby-on-rails and I'm using Shopify app proxy to make these 2 platforms work together. So the basic idea is that when I visit https://my-project.myshopify.com/a/portal it loads page https://my-project.c9users.io/a/portal with proxy.

Now the problem is that the rails flash is not working, and I think that is because of the proxy. Here are the codes I'm using:

Controller:

```
 if @article.save
    flash[:success] = "Article successfully saved!"
    redirect_to @article
```

View:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %>">
        <%= value %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

application_helper.rb:

```
def flash_class(level)
    case level
        when 'notice' then "alert alert-info"
        when 'success' then "alert alert-success"
        when 'error' then "alert alert-danger"
        when 'alert' then "alert alert-warning"
    end
end
```

The flash message works fine when I directly visit https://my-project.c9users.io/a/portal but with same form submission through https://my-project.myshopify.com/a/portal, which eventually loads https://my-project.c9users.io/a/portal does not seem to work.

So I guess the flash is getting lost during proxy request.

I have searched google many times for a solution but couldn't find one. Is there a rails way of solving this problem or should I just pass a parameter to the url when redirecting and then put the success message in the view? I know this would be an old fashion but is there a better way to go with?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `ActionDispatch::Flash` is an extremely temporary object and is certainly not Cross Site availble. You could pass a parameter or set up a small table to handle temporary persistence of the flashing across sites. e.g. insert a flash message into the table and pluck it out on the other end into an `ActionDispatch::Flash` object.

Comment: @engineersmnky could you please provide a reference tutorial as to how to achieve the second option you mentioned with database table?